# Significance test of Fisher z scores

Tags: correlation, z-score, fisher-transform

There are 14 vectors given, each vector has approx 3000 components that take vast range of values. I'd like to determine how closely linked they are or whether an independence could be assumed. I computed correlation coefficients for each pair of vectors. Then I transformed the coeff. into z scores. Here is an example of an output:

[image]

z scores:

[image]

The weird thing is that only for vector p4 the z score of the correlation with itself is not inf. It's also weird, that in R, I only had to input the correlation coefficient without any other information and it gave me a z score ( function FisherZ).
Anyway if my aim is to determine whether the vectors are significantly different from each other with confidence level of 95%, how can I do this using the correlation coefficient z transformations?

Comment: A random variable should show correlation of $1$ with itself, which would then transform to $+\infty$ and with a continuous random variable the null hypothesis of independence should always be rejected.   The values of $18.714974$ instead of $+\infty$ are likely to be due to tiny rounding errors producing a correlation of $0.9999999999999999$ rather than $1$

Comment: @Henry, although that's a plausible possibility, I find it strange that a Z score of 18.714974 corresponds to a p-value of 1.87E-78: that's not a value that would disappear in rounding using double-precision arithmetic.  This indicates any resolution of the question will require us to know exactly *how* the correlation coefficients were "transformed ... into z scores."  Gianni, could you please explain?  (Base `R` does not include a function named "FisherZ".)

Comment: @whuber apparently the [Fisher transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_transformation) is $z= \tanh^{-1}(r)= \log_e\sqrt{\frac{1+r}{1-r}}$.  All I did was spot   using $r=1-10^{-16}=0.9999999999999999$ gives $z=18.714974$.  Base R has the `atanh()` function while the DescTools package has `FisherZ()` and the psych package has `fisherz()` functions

Comment: @whuber I used FisherZ function from DescTools package. Though, that's not the main question, the question is how could I use these z scores to determine which vectors are meaningfully different from others. Is there a way to do this?